# How many official "Republics" are there in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I was wondering how many official "*Republics*" there are in the *Star Wars* universe?

One, two, three? I know about the **Old Republic** and the **New Republic** but I was wondering if there are any more.

Can the answerer please use the Star Wars movies or *Thrawn trilogy* (I am reading the first book now) as reference because only some of my Star Wars knowledge is on the Expanded Universe.

Note: to limit confusion in answers please show your estimated time periods for each republic.

Comment: Wikipedia says two. The old and the new.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you only use movies or Thrawn Trilogy, there were only two:

- Old [Galactic Republic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Old_Republic) (~25,000 years BBY - 19BBY)
- [The New Republic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/New_Republic) (post-Palpatine) (4ABY-27 ABY, though one may quibble that post-28ABY Alliance should be counted)

Thrawn trilogy didn't introduce any new ones. It mentioned several worlds but none of them held an official title of Republic.

However, Later EU had other smaller republics (Ylesian Republic,  Altirian Republic, Moralan republic).

Comment: Later EU had others (Ylesian Republic, for example)

Comment: If you think any of them are important you could list their time periods and put it in a separate category.

Comment: @jeffery - not as far as I can tell. All strictly local

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, DVK's separation into the New and Old Republic are correct. However, one could also argue that there were *three* Republics. Ruusan Reformations carried out after the New Sith Wars (Darth Bane era) ushered in a new "phase" to what we call the Old Republic. In fact, Palpatine refers to it in Attack of the Clones when he says "I will not let this Republic which as stood for a thousand years be split in two!" The EU has established that the Republic and Jedi Order are both around 25000 years old, but then why wouldn't Palpatine have just said that?

Answer (score 1):

For comprehension, I rather see it as Wikipedia does. "The Old Republic" ~25000 BBY, that formed into the "Galactic Republic" in 1032 BBY, [19BBY-4ABY was the Empires rise]  and then the "New Republic" as it was reorganised in 4BBY and then destroyed again in 34BBY in The Force Awakens.
So, two. But people often speak of the Old Republic and mean the "Galactic Republic" phase. At least as far as I understood!

Comment: You've named 3 however said there's only 2

Comment: I think some people need to update their answers but you deserve an upvote for providing additional useful information for the newer movies. Question: under Palpatine wouldn't "Galactic Republic" be "galactic empire"? Then you have the old republic and the new one in force awakens which seems to be unnamed.